# Where clause on a string rather than id

Tags: mysql

I need to get all articles out of my database if they fall under a category or sub category.

articles:

```
id | title | content | category_id (fk)
```

categories

```
id | title | parent_id
 1    toys      1
 2    trains    1
 3    pets      3
```

I perform:

```
SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN articles ON categories.id = articles.category_id WHERE categories.id = ? OR WHERE categories.parent_id = ?
```

The above works, but now I want to use the category title instead of an id. So something like:

```
SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN articles ON categories.id = articles.category_id WHERE **categories.title** = ? OR WHERE ??? not sure how to handle this bit
```

But im not sure how to handle the OR WHERE, as I don't know the categories id value.

Is there a way to do this without performing a category id lookup query first?

Answer (score 0):

You could, first, get a list of categories that are child categories of a parent  category and the parent category, then, join to find the matching articles.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM   categories
    WHERE  title = 'toys'
    UNION
    select a.*
    FROM   categories a
    JOIN   categories b ON (a.parent_id = b.id)
    WHERE  b.title = 'toys'
) c
JOIN articles ON (c.id = articles.category_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN articles ON c.id = articles.category_id
WHERE **c.title** = ? OR 
c.title IN (select title from categories ca where c.title = ? AND ca.id = c.parent_id)
```

You can control if title of row's parent match whether or not matches with special title. There might be more efficient ways but this design is very similar to yours.

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10405601)